# Can a Coin be liquid during its ICO period?

Tags: tokens, dapps

I am planning to run a Coin's ICO for several years, not interested in the gains to be made from selling out ICO in 3 days NO, but interested in using the COin to end Global Poverty as i deem fit. So a lenghty ICO is one solution. That said I want to know if its possible for the coin to be liquid during the ICO of like 2-4 years. If it is possible for its liquidity then suggest how that can be done please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the liquidity in the solidity contract. Most ICO's restrict the transfer of funds during the ICO using a start/stop function. However, to answer your question. You need 3 functions. Buy, Sell and set minimum price.

```
/**
* @dev Buys Tokens from contract in ether
*/
function () isRunning validAddress external payable {
    uint256 amount = msg.value;
    amount = amount.div(buyPrice);
    amount = amount.mul(10**18);
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);
    Buy(this, msg.sender, amount, buyPrice);
  }

/**
* @dev Sells Ether from contract in Token
* @param amount The amount of tokens to be sold
*/
function sell(uint256 amount) isRunning validAddress public {
    require(this.balance >= amount.mul(sellPrice));
    _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(amount.mul(sellPrice));
    Sell(msg.sender, this, amount, sellPrice);
}

/**
* @dev Sets Buy and Sell Prices
* @param newSellPrice The Sell Price
* @param newBuyPrice The Buy Price
*/
function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}
```

You would also need to send the tokens that you create back to the token contract, or create a new contract just for the liquidity.